# Мы оказываем полный цикл... услуг по ценам(,) доступным всем

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая?

Мы оказываем полный цикл амбулаторных и диагностических услуг по ценам, доступным всем категориям граждан.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая безусловно нужна, это обособленный определительный оборот, причастие с зависимыми словами.
Но фраза немного корявая. Вы уверены, что "доступные" - это удачная характеристика "цен"? Сильно отдает малограмотным рекламным слоганом. И не то плохо, что рекламным. А то, что малограмотным.

(+)

Может так.

***Мы оказываем полный цикл амбулаторных и диагностических услуг, доступных по цене всем категориям граждан.***

Хотя "категории граждан" - это тоже, конечно, чудо красноречия.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Очень помогли.